# I saw water droplets on the leaves of my dumb cane. Where did it come from? Is it harmful?

Tags: indoors

I saw water droplets on the leaves of my dumb cane. Where did it come from? Is it harmful?

For the time being I wiped the water with a cloth. What's should I have done?

Comment: I have already wiped it. @Stephie

Answer (score 2):

Likely [guttation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guttation). Wikipedia:

> At night, transpiration usually does not occur because most plants have their stomata closed. When there is a high soil moisture level, water will enter plant roots, because the water potential of the roots is lower than in the soil solution. The water will accumulate in the plant, creating a slight root pressure. The root pressure forces some water to exude through special leaf tip or edge structures, hydathodes or water glands, forming drops. Root pressure provides the impetus for this flow, rather than transpirational pull. Guttation is most noticeable when transpiration is suppressed and the relative humidity is high, such as during the night.

Comment: Whoa.  Wayfaring...really good answer.  This is Wikipedia's words?  Haven't heard or even seen these words for a long time...